# Set the Content-Type header dynamically in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

I have a controller method that serves a file decoded from a Base64 string.

```java
// Simplified from original
@GetMapping("/download/{id}")
public byte[] download(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    var doc = new Document("test.pdf", "application/pdf", "Base64 encoded data"); // This is loaded from elsewhere

    response.addHeader("Content-Type", doc.getType());
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"%s\"".formatted(doc.getFilename()));

    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(doc.getData());
}
```

When I set the header through `HttpServletResponse`, Spring seems to always override it to `text/html`. I can't set it with an annotation or configuration because I need to set it dynamically inside the controller method.

How do I set the Content-Type header dynamically without Spring overriding it?

Comment: How do you submit the request? Have you tried adding `produces` to the get mapping annotation?

Comment: I agree with @daniu, try `consumes` and `produces` annotations as first step

Comment: I only know what type I will be serving after the document is retrieved inside the function and I don't have a list of possible types beforehand so using an annotation isn't possible for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ResponseEntity` as a return type instead of manipulating the `Response`. The code can look as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/download/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> download(@PathVariable String id) throws Exception {
    var doc = new Document("test.pdf", "application/pdf", "Base64 encoded data");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", doc.getType());
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"%s\"".formatted(doc.getFilename()));

    return ResponseEntity
        .status(HttpStatus.OK)
        .headers(headers)
        .body(Base64.getDecoder().decode(doc.getData()));
}
```

You can also simplify setting of headers. Instead of using headers names

```
    headers.add("Content-Type", doc.getType());
```

you can use methods

```
    headers.setContentType(doc.getType());
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks.